# Is there a way to determine if emacs uses the byte compiled or the natively compiled code of a function?

Tags: byte-compilation, native-comp

Say, there is some function and if I do a `describe-function` on it it says:

```
x is an interactive compiled Lisp function in x.el
```

Can I tell somehow if this loaded compiled code is byte compiled or natively compiled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In emacs-28.1, `describe-function` gives this information:

> switch-to-buffer is an interactive native compiled Lisp function in
> ‘window.el’.

Comment: Thanks, I tried font-lock-mode, but that simply says  'interactive compiled Lisp function'. switch-to-buffer says native, though, for me too. I use the precompiled windows emacs binary, and I thought all lisp code  files in the distribution is native compiled, but apparently this is not the case.  I wonder why.

Comment: `font-lock-mode` is native compiled for me (emacs built from source on linux).

Answer (score 5):

Variable `system-configuration-features` will contain NATIVE_COMP if your Emacs has been compiled with native compilation support.